# What are the limitations on gcloud auth activate-service-account

Tags: google-cloud-platform

What is the limitations or best usage of `gcloud auth activate-service-account` within a linux CLI environment which mainly uses `gcloud` commands in scripts?

Is there a logout time period other than the GCP service account being deleted?

Is it best practice to login or authenticate every time before a `gcloud` command executes or just once at the creation of the provisioned resource?

Comment: From which server do you use the service account key file?

Comment: the gcp server which is executes gcloud commands on itself via python. Mainly resizing persistent disks when they are about to run out of free space automatically.

Comment: One challenge with running `gcloud` on e.g Compute Engine is that you need to provide the Service Account key to the script to be able to use `gcloud auth activate-service-account`. When running on e..g Compute Engine, it's better to use the Metadata service to access credentials and this is what Google's libraries do via [Application Default Credentials](https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#auth-cloud-implicit-python). Moving keys onto VMs to use `gcloud` is probably an anti-pattern.

Comment: You mention "gcloud commands ... via Python". This suggests that you're writing Python scripts that use `subprocess` to access `gcloud`. This is a "challenging" approach for many reasons. I encourage you to consider using Application Default Credentials and writing your scripts as pure Python using Google's Compute Engine library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the limitations or best usage of gcloud auth
> activate-service-account within a linux CLI environment which mainly
> uses gcloud commands in scripts?

The CLI is meant to be a developer tool. There are no other limitations that I am aware of for using the CLI in scripts.

> Is there a logout time period other than the GCP service account being
> deleted?
>
> Is it best practice to login or authenticate every time before a
> gcloud command executes or just once at the creation of the
> provisioned resource?

Service accounts do not login or logout. The OAuth tokens expire after 3600 seconds. The tokens created by the CLI will be refreshed automatically, so you do not need to re-authenticate.

Comment: Interesting, thank you for taking the time to explain to me the login concept when service accounts really use OAuth.